# Improve efficiency of bootstrap function

Tags: r, plyr, sample, boot, microbenchmark

I have a large dataframe from which I want to take random samples for each column. I'd like sample multiple times and store the sum of my results in a new dataframe.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(0:10, replace = T), nrow = 1000, ncol=60))
```

I have written a function to sample from my dataframe and calculate my statistics.

```
rd <- function(x) sample(x, size = N, replace =TRUE)
N <- nrow(df)

sampling <- function(df){
  df_s <- apply(df, 2, rd) 
  
  df_f <- df_s %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>%
    summarise_if(is.numeric, sum)
  }
```

I'd like to replicate this 10000 and save the summary statistics in a new dataframe.

```
reps <- 10
df_sums <- plyr::rdply(reps, sampling(df))
```

However, running this code 100 times alone seems to be very inefficient, it takes slightly longer with my original dataset.

```
microbenchmark(sampling(df), times = 100)
```

Any suggestion how I can make this more efficient so I can actually run my code 10000 times? I tried to write the function with `replicate`, but I couldn't get the output to look as  neat as with `rdply`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to resample single columns but can resample the whole data frame at once.

```r
sampling2 <- function(df) {
  colSums(df[sample(nrow(df), replace=T), ])
}
df_sums <- t(replicate(100, sampling2(df)))
```

This works much faster:

```r
microbenchmark(sampling(df),
               sampling2(df))
# Unit: milliseconds
#          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#  sampling(df) 62.047601 64.451151 77.350142 69.629501 81.000350 476.3357   100   b
# sampling2(df)  1.427401  1.562552  1.954756  1.654052  1.906201  13.3865   100  a
```

Please note that with this approach somewhat breaks the independence of values within the rows of `df_sums`. If that would be a problem, it can be solved by resampling the columns of `df_sums`:

```r
df_sums <- apply(df_sums, 2, sample)
```

Comment: These samples won't be independent across columns, e.g., the 1st value of the first column will always be sampled with the 1st value of the second column.

Comment: @jblood94 That's correct, if that is a problem for OP's application, they can always resample rows of the resulting matrix. I should probably be more explicit about this, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I should have been clearer about this (and I hope my code is doing that). I want to take random samples from each column, which are independent from other columns and independent from the row sampled from.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is sampling with replacement, you can trade memory for speed. Take 10k bootstrap samples times 1k rows = 10M samples of each column, put them in a 10k-by-1k matrix and take the row sums. The example matrix takes 30 seconds on my 8-year-old laptop.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(0:10, 6e4, 1), 1e3, 60))

library(Rfast)

system.time(
  sapply(df, \(x) rowsums(matrix(sample(x, 1e4*length(x), 1), 1e4)))
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   27.12    1.06   30.47
```